# How to restrict payment method by ip address in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

i want to restrict payment method show by ip restriction, only allowed ip will show some payment method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app/code/[vendor]/[module]/etc/frontend/event.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="ip_based_payment_method" instance="[vendor]/[module]\Observer\PaymentMethod"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**[vendor]/[module]\Observer\PaymentMethod**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace [vendor]\[module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Pivotal\DynamicRowConfig\Helper\Data;

class PaymentMethod implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Method will restrict payment methods
     * 'cashondelivery'
     * based on customer IP address
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $method = $observer->getMethodInstance();
        $result = $observer->getResult();
        $allowedIpAddresses = [110.227.195.70, 110.227.195.75];
        $userIpAddress = "110.227.195.70";
        // For $allowedIpAddresses you can create config and use that ip value


        if ($method->getCode() == "cashondelivery" &&
            !empty($allowedIpAddresses) &&
            !in_array($userIpAddress, $allowedIpAddresses)
        ) {
            $result->setIsAvailable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To restrict payment method by IP address in Magento 2 using a plugin, you would need to create a custom plugin that listens to the event **`"payment_method_is_active"`** and performs a check on the IP address of the user before allowing the payment method to be displayed. Here is an example of what the code for the plugin may look like:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;

class RestrictPaymentByIp
{
    protected $session;
    protected $request;
    protected $remoteAddress;

    public function __construct(
        Session $session,
        RequestInterface $request,
        RemoteAddress $remoteAddress
    ) {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
    }

    public function aroundIsActive(
        \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface $subject,
        callable $proceed
    ) {
        $allowedIps = ['127.0.0.1', '::1'];
        $ip = $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();

        if (!in_array($ip, $allowedIps)) {
            return false;
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

This plugin will check the IP address of the user and compare it to an array of allowed IPs, if the IP address is not in the array of allowed IPs, the plugin will return false, preventing the payment method from being displayed.

You would then need to define this plugin in your module's **`di.xml`** file so that magento can use it.

```
<type name="Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface">
    <plugin name="restrict_payment_by_ip" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\RestrictPaymentByIp" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**